# Given a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in a linear topological space, construct an open $W$ such that $W+W \subset U$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

A linear topological space is a space equipped with Hausdorff topology such that addition and scalar multiplication are continuous. I read in a book that when $X$ is a linear topological space and $U \subset X$ is a neighborhood of $0$, then there exists some neighborhood $W$ of $0$, such that $W=-W$ and $W+W \subset U$.

I know how to construct a $W$ so that $W=-W$. But how to make $W$ satisfies the second condition, i.e., $W+W \subset U$? When $X$ is locally convex, $W$ can be easily constructed, but the book I am reading doesn't assume local convexity of $X$..

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Addition is continuous. The pre-image of U under addition (as a subset of the product space $X \times X$) is open. So it must contain a product $W_1 \times W2$ of open neighborhoods of $0$. Can you build $W$ from $W_1$ and $W_2$?

Comment: @mathguy Great hint, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$m(x) = -x$ from $X$ to $X$ is a self-inverse homeomorphism from $X$ to $X$, so e.g. $m[W] = -W$ is an open set if $W is.

Also, $p: X \times X \to X, p(x,y) = x+y$ is continuous and $p( 0,0) = 0$, so $p^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X \times X$ and contains $(0,0)$. So there is a product open set $W_1 \times W_2$ containing $(0,0)$ such that $W_1 \times W_2 \subseteq p^{-1}[U]$. Define $W_3 = W_1 \cap W_2$ (which is an open neighbourhood of $0$), and finally define $W = W_3 \cap (-W_3)$ which is also open containing $0$. Clearly $$-W = m[W_3 \cap (-W_3)] = m[W_3] \cap m[-W_3] = -W_3 \cap W_3 = W$$ And if $x \in W, y \in W$ we know that $x \in W_3 \subseteq W_1, y \in W_3 \subseteq W_2$, so $x+y  =p(x,y) \in U$ as required: $W + W \subseteq U$.